# Allow users to sort images based on category selected (paperclip gem) - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, psql

Currently my home page (index.html.erb) shows all the user images loaded within the past 24 hours, which is part of posts. However I would like to add a form that allows the user to sort images based on their category and upload date. (For example images with the category music, uploaded within the past month) I understand how to query the database but I dont know how to take the user input. When I create a form, using simple form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @posts do |f| %>
```

it throws an error, saying I cannot use an object. Ive also tried ajax but it doesnt seem to work well with the paperclip gem, plus I rather get it done on the backend. I hope I explained my issue well enough. If not feel free to comment as I will be around to respond. Thanks in advance.

```
Post Controller:
 def index  
 @posts = Post.all.where(created_at:(Time.now - 1.day)..Time.now)
 end
```

Schema for Post table:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.string   "instagram"
t.text     "description"
t.string   "category"
t.datetime "created_at",                            null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                            null: false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
```

Comment: have you any category associated with post ?

Comment: Oops. Good call. Not yet but I can simply add that in a migration. But that is not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form that will submit to the same action (I'm assuming `posts_path` based on the controller/action) using the same HTTP verb (GET):

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, method: :get do =>
  …
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Then, within the `form_tag` block, add the field you want to use for filtering, e.g.:

```
<%= text_field_tag :category %>
```

You can then filter off this field conditionally in the controller:

```
@posts = @posts.where(category: params[:category]) if params[:category].present?
```